# OpenTelemetry Spanmetrics exclude_dimensions notation

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I see OpenTelemetry contrib `spanmetric` has `exclude_dimensions` field, with the example:

```
exclude_dimensions: ['status.code']
```

so I tried removing most of the default dimensions it adds from the trace context:

```
exclude_dimensions: ['container_id','host_arch','host_name','job','k8s_deployment_name','k8s_pod_start_time','os_description','os_type','process_command_args','process_executable_path','process_pid','process_runtime_description','process_runtime_name','process_runtime_version','telemetry_auto_version','telemetry_sdk_language','telemetry_sdk_name','telemetry_sdk_version']
```

Despite that, no label were excluded, I still see all being exported, even the ones without `_`, like `'job'`.

I wonder what would be the correct notation to remove the default labels.

I tried also with '.' in place of '_' but then no metric got exported.